# How do I resolve "Identifier not found or not unique" in solidity?

Tags: string, function, solidity, identifier

I'm a newb with no coding experience, so pardon me for asking something this simple. I've got the following code below for a simple smart contract that I'm building through a udemy course. I've got the following error code: "Identifier not found or not unique. [Ln 21, Col 27]" Can anyone help tell me what's wrong with the code. Ln 21, Col 27 is the "setGreetings" function below. Thanks in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FppBd.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in your **setGreetings** function argument. We first have to specify the data type of the argument then the storage location like memory, calldata etc.
So correct function would be in order like this

```
function setGreetings(string calldata _message){
message=_message;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So, now I'm getting "Return argument type string storage ref is not implicitly convertible to expected type (type of first return variable) string calldata." for the getGreetings function. Any suggestions to solve this?